# MIME type of outlook email

Tags: javascript, browser

In my application, there is a feature to upload files. Due to some reason, the file type for outlook email (.msg) is empty.

[image]

This happens with only .msg files(at least I'm aware of), for other files, this is working fine.

[image]

Why browsers are not able to detect mime type for .msg files. Or is there something I am doing it wrong